# How to pass custom enum in @Query via Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a simple enum:

```java
public enum Season {
    @SerializedName("0")
    AUTUMN,
    @SerializedName("1")
    SPRING;
}
```

Starting some version, GSON became able to parse such enums. To make sure, I did this:

```java
final String s = gson.toJson(Season.AUTUMN);
```

It works as I expected. Output is `"0"`. So, I tried use it in my Retrofit services:

```java
@GET("index.php?page[api]=test")
Observable<List<Month>> getMonths(@Query("season_lookup") Season season);
/*...some files later...*/
service.getMonths(Season.AUTUMN);
```

And also added logging to be really certain about its result:

```java
HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        .build();
```

But it failed. `@Query` totally ignored `@SerializedName` and used `.toString()` instead, so the log shown me `.../index.php?page[api]=test&season_lookup=AUTUMN`.

I traced Retrofit sources and found file `RequestFactoryParser` with lines :

```java
Converter<?, String> converter = 
    retrofit.stringConverter(parameterType, parameterAnnotations);
action = new RequestAction.Query<>(name, converter, encoded);
```

It seems, like it doesn't care at all about enums. Before these lines, it tested `rawParameterType.isArray()` to be an array or `Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom()` and nothing more.

Retrofit instance creation is:

```java
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiConstants.API_ENDPOINT)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

`gson` is `GsonBuilder().create()`. I peeked at sources, there is predefined `ENUM_TypeAdapters.ENUM_FACTORY` in it for enums, so I leave it as it is.

---

**The question is what can I do, to prevent using** `toString()` **on my enums and use** `@SerializedName`**? I use** `toString()` **for other purposes.**

Comment: Do you have proper converter added to your Retrofit? https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters

Comment: It seems that Retrofit uses Gson while serializing <pre>@Body</pre>, but not <pre>@Query</pre>, because with <pre>@Body</pre> it is serialized right way.

Comment: @DawidSzydło, but is there any way to write something like convertor for `Enum<?>` only? I would like to use reflection in that for `@SerializedName`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As @DawidSzydło mentioned, I misunderstood `Gson` usage in the Retrofit. It is used only for response/request decoding/encoding, but not for `@Query/@Url/@Path e.t.c`. For them, Retrofit uses `Converter.Factory` to convert any type to `String`.
Here is code for auto using `@SerializedName` as value of any `Enum` when passing it to Retrofit services.

Converter:

```
public class EnumRetrofitConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    @Override
    public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Converter<?, String> converter = null;
        if (type instanceof Class && ((Class<?>)type).isEnum()) {
            converter = value -> EnumUtils.GetSerializedNameValue((Enum) value);
        }
        return converter;
    }
}
```

EnumUtils:

```
public class EnumUtils {
    @Nullable
    static public <E extends Enum<E>> String GetSerializedNameValue(E e) {
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = e.getClass().getField(e.name()).getAnnotation(SerializedName.class).value();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Retrofit creation:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(ApiConstants.API_ENDPOINT)
        .client(httpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addConverterFactory(new EnumRetrofitConverterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

---

**08.18 update** added kotlin analog:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build()

        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.ENDPOINT)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addConverterFactory(EnumConverterFactory())
                .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
        service.getMonths(Season.AUTUMN).enqueue(object : Callback<List<String>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<String>>?, t: Throwable?) {
                /* ignore */
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<String>>?, response: Response<List<String>>?) {
                /* ignore */
            }
        })
    }
}

class EnumConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {
    override fun stringConverter(type: Type?, annotations: Array<out Annotation>?,
                                 retrofit: Retrofit?): Converter<*, String>? {
        if (type is Class<*> && type.isEnum) {
            return Converter<Any?, String> { value -> getSerializedNameValue(value as Enum<*>) }
        }
        return null
    }
}

fun <E : Enum<*>> getSerializedNameValue(e: E): String {
    try {
        return e.javaClass.getField(e.name).getAnnotation(SerializedName::class.java).value
    } catch (exception: NoSuchFieldException) {
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }

    return ""
}

enum class Season {
    @SerializedName("0")
    AUTUMN,
    @SerializedName("1")
    SPRING
}

interface Api {
    @GET("index.php?page[api]=test")
    fun getMonths(@Query("season_lookup") season: Season): Call<List<String>>

    companion object {
        const val ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

In logs you will see this:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://127.0.0.1/index.php?page[api]=test&season_lookup=0 
D/OkHttp: --> END GET 
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:80
```

Used dependencies are:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Looks fine, but it will fail if you want use enum without serialized name annotation in other requests. Basically there will be quick fix for that: in catch in your helper class you should set value value to enum value in case if there is no annotation used.

Comment: @Nexen Can you please also post the equivalent Kotlin code for this ?

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji, it is actually quite straightforward to convert java to kotlin, but you have a point. Kotlin era has come. I'll add that

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need it for all enums, I guess you can also skip the `Converter.Factory` setup and just add a `toString` method:

```
enum class Season {
    @SerializedName("0")
    AUTUMN,
    @SerializedName("1")
    SPRING;

    override fun toString(): String {
        return javaClass
                .getField(name)
                .getAnnotation(SerializedName::class.java)
                .value
    }
}
```

Or, if you need it for more than one:

```
val <E : Enum<E>> Enum<E>.serializedName: String
    get() = javaClass
            .getField(name)
            .getAnnotation(SerializedName::class.java)
            .value

enum class Season {
    @SerializedName("0")
    AUTUMN,
    @SerializedName("1")
    SPRING;

    override fun toString() = serializedName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@arekolek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500991/2914140) I wrote so:

```
enum class Type(val n: Int) {
    USER(1),
    GROUP(2);

    override fun toString(): String = n.toString() // Add this method
}

@GET("/profile")
suspend fun profile(@Query("type") type: Type): String
```

In this case the request "/profile" receives Int parameter "type", but we replaces Int with Type.