# Facebook api passing array param

Tags: java, android, facebook, kotlin

I want to get places by category by this request:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search?type=place&center={lat,lng}&categories=["FOOD_BEVERAGE"]](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/search?type=place&center=%7Blat,lng%7D&categories=%5B%22FOOD_BEVERAGE%22%5D)

I'm sending categories as query with retrofit as `List<String>`

But it returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message":"(#100) For field 'placesearch': param categories must be an array.",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":100,
    }
}
```

I was trying to do this by `ArrayList`, making this query as `String` literaly but it still return me that it need an array.
How can I pass this ?

#### EDIT:

Retrofit interface

```
@GET("search")
fun getPlaces(
       @Query("center") center: String?,
       @Query("access_token") token: String?,
       @Query("type") type: String?,
       @Query("categories") categories: List<String>
): Observable<Places>
```

Comment: Please include the source code of your retrofit interface

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I added

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom converter factory that converts a `List<String>` into a `String` of the correct format. Check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793344/how-to-pass-custom-enum-in-query-via-retrofit), instead of an `Enum` you have a `List<String>` and at the `GetSerializedNameValue()` method you would instead use:

```
value = categories_list.joinToString(
    separator = ", ",
    prefix = "[",
    postfix = "]"
)
```