# Compare Kotlin type and java class

Tags: class, types, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a request convertor like in this question except for JodaDateTime
[How to pass custom enum in @Query via Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793344/how-to-pass-custom-enum-in-query-via-retrofit)

However I'm struggling comparing the type that's passed in with the Joda Date Time class.

```
class JodaDateConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun stringConverter(
        type: Type?, annotations: Array<out Annotation>?,
        retrofit: Retrofit?
    ): Converter<*, String>? {
        if (type is Class<*> && type==DateTime::class) {
          return Converter<Any?, String> { value -> (value as DateTime).toString("yyyy-MM-dd") }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

type==DateTime::class is returning false.

I can see that type holds a string representing the Joda Date Time but I'm obviously comparing them incorrectly.

What is the correct way to compare a kotlin type and a java class?

Comment: Note that `type is Class<*> &&` is redundant: if the (fixed) comparison succeeds, `type is Class<*>` is certainly true.

Comment: Thanks Alexey that's useful to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Java type, use the syntax

```
DateTime::class.java
```

Comment: Fab thanks! - I tried a number of similar things but missed that one!